# jQuery mouseenter() fires when content is reloaded

Tags: jquery, html

First, here is a simplified example of my code that shows the problem :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style>
            .container {
                padding: 100px;
                background-color: red;
            }

            .content {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
        <script>
            function changeContainer()
            {
                $(".container").html("<div class='content'></div>");
            }

            $(function() {
                $(".container").mouseenter(function(){
                    window.setTimeout(changeContainer,100);
                    $("body").append("enter!<br/>");                    
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4rpv1pfa/1/

**The desired behavior :**

When I enter the container div with my mouse, it reloads its content with ajax (in the example code, a setTimeout simulates the ajax response delay).

**The problem :**

If I enter the container div with my mouse, then wait for its content to be reloaded before entering the content div, everything is fine but if I quickly enter the content div without waiting, the mouseenter event fires each time I move my mouse in the content div even if I don't move out of the container div.

This problem doesn't seems to happen with Internet Explorer. It's specified in the [jQuery mouseenter() documentation page](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) that the event only exists for Internet Explorer and it is simulated for other browser so I suppose it's the reason it only works in Internet Explorer

Comment: Yes, jQuery emulates this event for other browsers that do not have it implemented natively. The “problem” with mouseover/-out is that they fire when you move the cursor over descendant elements, and that is often unwanted. To implement mouseenter and mouseleave, jQuery AFAIK uses the native mouseover/-out events, and then checks whether the event target is inside or outside of the element; looks like that does not take into account dynamically replaced content correctly. (Could be some internal caching for performance reasons.)